# compere string using batch script

Tags: batch-file

i would like to create batch script that go over list of jpeg files (c:\jpeg) and list folders names (c:\empty_folders). the folder name include name and id (e.x John_1234).
if part of the folder name is match to the ID or name the jpg file should be copy to this folder.
so for example if have jpg file name lisa_adams_1234.jpg and folder name lisa_adams the jpf file should be copy to the folder lisa_adams located in c:\empty_folder .
 if someone can help me .

thanks !

Comment: You should provide an example of the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%F IN ("c:\jpeg\*.jpg") DO (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('dir /b /a:d "c:\empty_folders\*"') do (
    ECHO %%~nF | FINDSTR /C:"%%~nD" >nul & IF !errorlevel! equ 0 (
      ECHO copying %%~nF to %%~nD
      copy "%%F" "%%D"
    )
  )
)
pause
```

This tests if a Foldername is part of the Filename, and copies the file to the folder it that's true

A note: are the jpeg files called jpg or jpeg? You may need to change the code depending on that.

Comment: @Stephan totally forgot to add ECHO there, you're right